# How to extract text between parentheses within a longer string using awk?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, pattern-matching

I'm somewhat a beginner with awk/regex, so I apologize for the noobish question. I seem to have the hardest time with awk when the fields are combined. I have a longer awk script that is parsing several flat-file tables, but I'm running into some trouble with this particular column.

My data looks like this:

```
           EFGH1234
    (ABCD#)EFGH1234
  (LMNOPQ#)RSTU6789
```

I'm trying to separate the text in parentheses as it's own column, like so:

```
          EFGH1234
    ABCD  EFGH1234
  LMNOPQ  RSTU6789
```

I've tried searching and so far have found more complex expressions than what I'm trying to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to create extra 'columns' so that you can work with them. Split your field into an array using the [`split()` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). And, if you keep a count of the number of elements/keys that split creates, you can use this count as a test. For example:

```
awk '{ n = split($1, a, /[()#]/); print (n==1 ? $0 : a[2] FS a[4]) }' file
```

Results:

```
           EFGH1234
ABCD EFGH1234
LMNOPQ RSTU6789
```

Comment: I do have another similar column that I'll try this on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?I guess here by extraction  you meant remove the paranthesis.

```
perl -pe 's/[\(|\)|\#]/ /g' your_file
```

or in awk:

```
awk 'gsub("[(|#)]"," "){print}' your_file
    ABCD EFGH1234
  LMNOPQ RSTU6789
  LMNOPQ  RSTU6789
```

Comment: Better written as: `awk '{ gsub(/[(#)]/," ") }1' your_file`. Also, your output looks wrong.